# REST Jersey GET PUT conflict

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, jersey

I am using jersey version 1.17.1 + tomcat 7.0.39 + Spring MVC 3.2.1.

The problem is that I am not able to figure out why my PUT handler stops working when I extend a @Path of a GET handler?

The following configuration/matching in my Spring MVC controller works as expected:

```
 @GET
 @Path("/{id}")   // <--- WORKS!
 [...]

 @PUT
 @Path("/{id}")   // <--- WORKS!  
 [...]
```

but **whenever I extend matching of the GET** handler in order to be able to
handle not only

```
/anyId
```

requests but also requests of the forms

```
/anyId/
/anyId/anyfile.ext
```

then not touched **the PUT matching stops to work**:

```
 @GET
 @Path("/{id:.*[^/]}{fileName:.*}")   // <--- WORKS!
 [...]

 @PUT
 @Path("/{id}")                       // <--- Not working any longer: 
                                      //      "405 Method Not Allowed" 
 [...]
```

After changing matching of the GET Path to that above PUT requests get "405 Method Not Allowed" status code.

When I simplify back the GET Path like in the first case the PUT handler starts working again.

Is it a bug of Jersey or what?

Answer (score 1):

The 405 indicates that there was no method matching that which was in the request for that resource. This would indicate that *something* (or several somethings) had a matching `@Path` annotation, but that (Java) method did not have the right method. (If you can, turn on verbose debugging when looking at what's going on; it helps. Turn it off when you're done though; it's going to be far too verbose for normally being left on.)

Now, it helps to understand that `@Path` is mapped to a regular expression that matches against the path in the request, and that if you don't specify otherwise, a path template portion (the `{id}`) is effectively matched by the regular expression `[^?/;]+`, i.e., as many as possible characters without going into the next part of the path, the query part, or any matrix parameters. (Don't know what a matrix parameter is? You probably don't *want* to know!)

In order to match all these forms:

```
/anyId    
/anyId/
/anyId/anyfile.ext
```

you are best off using two Java methods per HTTP method:

```
@GET @Path("{id}")
…
@GET @Path("{id}/{file:.*}")
…
```

This works, but it's verbose.

---

It might be easier to instead return an object that represents the resource and which has the operations defined on it:

```
class MyResource {
    private String id, file;
    MyResource(String id, String file) {
        this.id = id; this.file = file;
    }
    // Can't remember if @Path is needed on these; "/" is a special case IIRC
    @GET @Path("/") @Produces(…)
    public String get() { … }
    @PUT @Path("/") @Produces(…) @Consumes(…)
    public String put(String message) { … }
}
```

```
@Path("{id}")
public MyResource getNoPath(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    return new MyResource(id, null);
}
@Path("{id}/{file:.*}")
public MyResource getNoPath(@PathParam("id") String id, @PathParam("file") String file) {
    return new MyResource(id, file);
}
```

Like that, you split the code that parses the path from the code that serves up the right method. I do this thing with CXF (another JAX-RS implementation) and it works rather well.

Comment: Donald, as I described in my post my GET handler **always** works: before and after extending it so that it can handle requests ending with a file name. The problem is that when I extend GET @Path the PUT handler stops being matched. I tried to split my GET handler into two separate ones. And again, after that PUT handler stopped working...

Answer (score 0):

A 405 generally means that a suitable method could not be found.  Hard to tell with only the small snippet you have provided but you need to ensure that you have appropriate `@Consumes` annotations on your `PUT` methods.

You might also try changing your `@Path` to something like `@Path("{id: [^/]+}/{fileName: .+}")` and see if that helps.  If not, please supply your full controller.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the controllers do not matter here. I skipped them on purpose. I have verified it using remote debugging. When I use the simpler mapping both methods (@Path's) work fine - both controllers are entered as expected. But it is enough to extend the GET @Path with the regular expression then the **PUT** handler stops working and server returns 'Method not allowed' (the extended GET matching works ok).